# Segulah of saying 13 times perek 13 of tehillim

Tags: sources-mekorot, tehilim-psalms, segulah

I have heard a number of times of a segulah to say perek 13 of tehillim 13 times. Does anyone know the source of such a segulah?

Comment: How do you even  know such a thing exists?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8+%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%99'%D7%92+%D7%99'%D7%92+%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D    http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2846052&forum_id=771     http://www.prog.co.il/archive/index.php/t-136342.html                   http://vitaminim.org/1/index.php?topic=336.0  especially the last one

Comment: הרב דניאל פריש זצ"ל,  יה מרבה להמליץ לכל נצרכי ישועה ורפואה לומר את פרק י"ג של תהילים י"ג פעמים במשך י"ג ימים.הוא לא גילה את מקור הסגולה הזו, אולם המוני הנושעים בה יעידו כי הוראה זו של הרב זצ"ל חוללה נפלאות.
ואם אמנם שלא נדע ונשכיל שורש ענינה, אולם גלוי וידוע הוא שהמספר י"ג הינו מבורך, ובזוהר הקדוש עצמו מצאנו שמוזכר כוחו הגדול של המספר י"ג, ששורשו בי"ג מידות של רחמים וי"ג מידות שהתורה נדרשת בהן, בן י"ג למצוות ועוד. עיין במהרש"א מסכת שבת דף קי"ט עמוד ב' אכן, בספרי התהילים בהם מופיעים עניניהם של כל אחד מהפרקים, הסברים המבוארים מקדמונים, מוזכר לפני פרק זה כי הוא סגולה גדולה להניצל מכל צרה ומצור.

Comment: @Double AA It does seem to

Comment: Why the downvote. Its a perfectly good question although one could check on google easily like I did. One cant always proves such a thing exists with this kind of question.

Comment: i had the same question but i'm sick of trying to understand why things get downvoted. I once tried to discuss it with the moderators, but not much luck. either way as long as people can gain, who cares about the votes.

Comment: @preferred if you transfer your comment to an answer I'll tick it.

Comment: does anyone know where to get a copy of עלון השפעת מתיקות הזוהר where the words of harav frish are qouted

Comment: @rabbi Thanks, but as I wrote all I did was go to google.

Comment: Be very careful not to transgress Nichus, when saying verses, as mentioned in this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38403/501

Comment: I have a group of 30 women from around the world saying Kapittel Yud Gimmel 13 times on each 13th of the Hebrew month. Baruch Hashem we are now saying for a full year. We have had success with 15 Chassanim and Kallos. I am talking about the whole world mamash! Australia, Vienna, Antwerp, London, Canada, Yerushalaim and Gibraltar

Comment: According to Rambam, one who does so forfeits his share in the world to come: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64570/8775.

Answer (score 1):

The Rav Wattenberg write [here](https://www.techouvot.com/segoula_du_tehilim_13-vp56368.html?highlight=tehilim#56368) that it is a Segula from the Rav Daniel Frish (1935-2005), author of the Matok Midvash. He also discuss there the merits of this (kind of) segula(ot).