# Raziel Hamalach Book as a Segula

Tags: jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, segulah, superstition

What is the origin of owning the book Raziel Hamalach as a segula for protection against harm?

Comment: See [here](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/772117/Rabbi_Hershel_Schachter/Segulas,_Superstition,_and_the_Ayin_Hara)

Comment: This question would be much more valuable and answerable if you'd include information about what this book is, who wrote it, etc., as well as whatever you can say about where you heard about the idea for which you're seeking an origin.

Comment: I assume the origin is the guys who wanted to sell them as key chains.  They were partnering with the red string dealers.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I don't think he knows that either....http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40281/5323 was asked by him at around the same time....

Comment: @Shokhet could you please summarize what Rabbi Shachter says there about this issue?

Comment: @Jewels He doesn't say anything about Raziel Hamalach, sorry, should've been clearer about that....see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38415/5323

Comment: IMHO (until someone teaches me otherwise) this is one of those things that doesn't make sense, and may therefore be an _issur d'oraysa_

Comment: But seriously @Jewels , I really should have been clearer about what I meant, and for that I apologize