# Knife on top of door lintel- segulah

Tags: segulah

I have seen two seprate restaurants that placed a knife ontop of the entrance door's lintel. I was wondering what is the reason for this,I suspect its some sort of segulah,but I am not sure. Does anyone know of such a segulah?

Comment: Sounds dangerous

Comment: Its something hard to notice unless you happen to like to look around your surroundings often

Comment: If it's a restaurant it could just be decoration.

Comment: I doubt it being a decoration,it looks like it was specifically placed ont top of the entrance door because that is where its supposed to be,also its out of ones view,one needs to look for it

Comment: "The importance of the tool is evident in the way they were stored in the old days. The axes were kept in a rack above the main door so it would be readily available when venturing out." — http://northernwildernesskills.blogspot.com/2013/08/all-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about.html

Comment: I'm reminded of archaeologists wondering why axes and knives were stored high up, sometimes by being driven into a beam, until someone pointed out that it was to keep them out of reach of children.

Answer (score 1):

This superstition seems to not be specifically Jewish. See The Penguin Guide to the Superstitions of Britain and Ireland [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Mc4qPiICvcC&pg=PT962&lpg=PT962&dq=superstition+knife+lintel&source=bl&ots=LTgZ4Q2hIg&sig=Wga_uRUDRdquad_F7FVYhBGoyIU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizmeuUjfPSAhWe0YMKHWBpDTAQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=superstition%20knife%20lintel&f=false), which states:

> A knife stuck into a mast or a door lintel is good luck.

See there for more knife related superstitions. It should be noted that this version involves sticking the knife into the lintel, rather than placing it on the lintel. Perhaps the version of placing it into the lintel is related to [an older superstition](https://books.google.com/books?id=FPIGAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=superstition+knife+lintel&source=bl&ots=paYel2KyzY&sig=omcMZXqJdySmvqUcK8Ah5TcDJNs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizmeuUjfPSAhWe0YMKHWBpDTAQ6AEIPzAH#v=onepage&q=superstition%20knife%20lintel&f=false); dating back to Pliny, of affixing iron coffin nails to the lintel of door for good luck.

Comment: so is it *asur* because of *darkei emori*?

Comment: @Ploni That seems likely. The general question of which non-Jewish superstitions are biblically forbidden was asked [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38403/8775). Several justifications for prevalent (primarily Ashkenazi) superstitions are listed by the Aharonim there. Note that the Hokhmat Adam references in the first answer is completely misunderstood.