# What is the source for saying Parshas Hamon is a Segullah for Parnassah?

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, beshalach, segulah

It is said in the name of Reb Mendel M'Riminov that saying [Parshas Ha'monn](http://www.tefillos.com/parshas_hamon.asp) (Shneyim Mikroh V'Echod Targum) on Tuesday Parshas B'Shalach, is a Segulah for Parnasah. Does anyone know a source for this "Minhag"?

Comment: I couldn't find any other source (but Rabbi Menahem Mendel M'Rimnov) for saying it specifically on Tuesday Parshas B'Shalach, but sources for saying the *parsha* for *parnassah* are abundant (see also external links there for a full article on the subject): https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F

Comment: I couldn't find a source, but there may be one. But even if there isn't, *segulot* (real ones) are many times simply good advice, with great knowledge and wisdom about the world and *Hashem*'s workings in it. For this, there's no need for formal sources, like there is in *halacha*.

Comment: I've heard that one should say parshat Hamon daily. I see it listed in many Nuscah Ashkenaz siddurim. I wouldn't know if it is considered "segulah*, but th econnection to parnassa seems quite obvious. We should always be aware that our "daily bread" comes as a gift from G-d and not via the work of our own hands. By "bread", I mean money as well as actual physical bread.

Comment: See: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44058/is-it-appropriately-jewish-to-use-psalms-as-a-form-of-talisman/64570#64570

Answer (score 7):

According to R. [Amnon Bazak](https://www.facebook.com/amnon.d.bazak/photos/a.233235363479660.60990.233065886829941/721839101285948/?type=3&theater), there is no source, and it in fact goes against tradition. Although the custom to recite "Parshat ha-Man" appears in the first siman of Shulchan Aruch, there it is a practice for every day, "in order that one should believe that his food comes with divine providence." This practice was not widely accepted.
Some poskim quote a midrash (whose source is not otherwise known) according to which one who recites Parshat ha-Man *every day* is guaranteed not to lose his food supply. Those who promote saying Parshat ha-Man on Tuesday of Beshalach claim that it is based on R. Mendel of Rimanov, who did dedicate much of his teaching to Parshat ha-Man. However, this segulah is not mentioned in any of his seforim, nor in any other sefer of Torah literature. Instead of searching for segulot, we would do better to heed the words of the Torah:

"וְהָיָה אִם שָׁמֹעַ תִּשְׁמְעוּ אֶל מִצְוֹתַי אֲשֶׁר אָנֹכִי מְצַוֶּה אֶתְכֶם הַיּוֹם לְאַהֲבָה אֶת ה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם וּלְעָבְדוֹ בְּכָל לְבַבְכֶם וּבְכָל נַפְשְׁכֶם. וְנָתַתִּי מְטַר אַרְצְכֶם בְּעִתּוֹ יוֹרֶה וּמַלְקוֹשׁ וְאָסַפְתָּ דְגָנֶךָ וְתִירֹשְׁךָ וְיִצְהָרֶךָ. וְנָתַתִּי עֵשֶׂב בְּשָׂדְךָ לִבְהֶמְתֶּךָ וְאָכַלְתָּ וְשָׂבָעְתָּ".