# How does this Midrash Tanchuma relate to God guarding 'like the pupil of His eye'?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, haazinu

In the last [Midrash Tanchuma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanhuma) in Parshas Haazinu is the following:

(*Translation omitted; Source provided by [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ha%27Azinu.8.1?vhe=Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet&lang=bi)*)

> **יצרנהו כאישון עינו.** הקדוש ברוך הוא נוצר לבחוניו, כאדם הנוצר אישון עינו. ומעשה באדם אחד עשיר גדול ומקובל, והיתה לו בת אחת יפת תואר מאד וחסידה. ונשאת שלשה פעמים לשלשה בני אדם, ובכל לילה ראשונה של נשואיה, למחרת מוצאים בעלה מת. אמרה, לא ימותו עוד בני אדם עלי, אשב אלמנה ועגונה עד אשר יראה המקום וירחם. ישבה ימים רבים. והיה לאותו עשיר אח עני מאד במדינה אחרת, והיו לו עשרה בנים, ובכל יום ויום הוא ובנו הגדול מביאין חבילי עצים מן היער ומוכרין אותן ומזה היו מתפרנסין הוא ואשתו ובניו. פעם אחת לא מכרו ולא היה להם מעות לקנות לחם, ולא אכלו אותו היום. למחר [מה] היה להם. הלכו ביער ונתעטף רוח האב. זלגו עיני הבן דמעות על ענים ותלה עיניו למרום. הרהר הבן בלבו נטל רשות מאביו ומאמו והלך למדינת דודו. וכשבא לביתו שמח שמחה גדולה דודו עליו וגם אשתו ובתו, ושאלו לו על אביו ועל אמו ועל הבנים. ישב עמו שבעה ימים. לסוף שבעת ימים, בא הבחור לדודו, אמר לו, שאלה אחת אני שואל ממך, אל תשיבני. אמר לו דודו, אמור בני מה שתרצה. אמר לו, השבעה לי. וכן עשה. אמר, זאת השאלה אשר אני שואל ממך, שתתן לי בתך לאשה. כששמע האיש בכה, אמר לו, אל בני, אל, כי בעונותי כך מדתה. אמר לו, על מנת כך. אמר לו, אם על עסקי ממוני אתה קופץ עליה, אל תשאנה, ואני אתן לך כסף וזהב הרבה, כי אתה בחור נאה וחכם, ובעצתי, אל תסתכן בה. אמר לו, כבר נשבעת על הדבר הזה. ראה העשיר הדבר ונתרצה לו, ובא לבתו וספר לה את הדברים. כששמעה זאת, בכתה וצעקה במר נפשה, ותלתה עיניה למרום, ואמרה, רבון העולמים, תהי ידך בי, ואל ימותו כל אלו עלי. מה עשה. קדשה ועשה משתה וקרא לזקני העיר, ועשה כילה וישב החתן בתוכה. ונזדמן לו זקן אחד והוא אליהו זכור לטוב, וקראו בינו לבינו, ואמר לו, בני, איעצך עצה נכונה ואל תט מעצתי. כשתשב לסעוד, יבא אליך עני לבוש בגדים שחורים וקרועים, יחף ויגע, שער נתנו מסמרים, עני שאין כמוהו בכל העולם. כשתראהו, תקום ממושבך והושיבהו אצלך, והאכילהו והשקהו ושמש לפניו בכל כחך וכבדהו, ואל תפל דבר מכל אשר דברתי לך, ותשאר לשלום, ואני אלך לדרכי. הלך לו הזקן ובא החתן למקומו. ישבו על המשתה. כשהתחילו לאכול, בא אותו עני. וכשראהו החתן עמד ממקומו ועשה לו כל מה שאמר לו הזקן. לאחר המשתה, אותו העני קרא לחתן, הביאו לחדר, אמר לו, בני, אני שלוחו של מקום, ובאתי הנה לקחת את נפשך. אמר לו, אדוני, תן לי זמן שנה אחת או חצי שנה. אמר ליה, לא אעשה. אמר לו, אם כן, תן לי שלשים יום או שבעה ימי המשתה. אמר לו, לא אתן לך אפילו יום אחד כי כבר הגיע עתך. אמר לו, בבקשה ממך המתן לי עד שאלך ואקח רשות מאשתי. אמר לו, לדבר הזה אשא פניך, ולך בא מהרה. הלך לחדר, והיא יושבת יחידה ובוכה ומתפללת לקונה (ופתח החדר). קרא הבחור אליה, ובאת לפתוח לו. הביאהו אצל' בחדר, החזיקה בו ונשקה לו. אמרה לו, אחי, למה באת. אמר לה, ליטול רשות ממך, כי בא עתי ללכת בדרך כל הארץ, כי המלאך בא והגיד לי, שבא לבקש את נפשי. אמרה לו, לא תלך אלא תשב הנה, ואני אלך לו ואדברה עמו. הלכה ומצאה אותו. אמרה לו, אתה המלאך שבאת לבקש נפש אישי. אמר לה, הן. אמרה לו, לא ימות עתה. כתוב בתורה, כי יקח איש אשה חדשה לא יצא בצבא ולא יעבור עליו לכל דבר, נקי יהיה לביתו שנה אחת ושמח את אשתו אשר לקח (דברים כד ה). והקדוש ברוך הוא אמת ותורתו אמת. ואם תקח את נפשו, תעשה התורה פלסתר. אם תקבל דברי, מוטב. ואם לאו, תבוא עמי לבית דין הגדול. מיד גער הקדוש ברוך הוא במלאך והלך. בלילה שכבו יחד החתן והכלה, ואבי הכלה ואמה בוכים בחדרם וכשהגיע לחצי הלילה, קמו האיש והאשה להכין קבר לחתנם קודם שיעלה עמוד השחר. כשקמו שמעו החתן והכלה משחקין ושמחים יחד. נכנסו לחדר לראות הדבר, ראו ושמחו והודיעו הדבר לקהל והודו לשם. וזהו שהקדוש ברוך הוא נוצר הבוטחים בו]

The Midrash opens with הקדוש ברוך הוא נוצר לבחוניו, כאדם הנוצר אישון עינו "*G-d protects his chosen ones, like man protects the pupil of his eye*" and then provides a story which doesn't seem to provide support for this. How does one understand this Midrash?

Additionally, I'm looking sources that can provide other insights to this Midrash. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW I can't find this in R. Buber's ed. of the Tanhuma, or in Mann's ed. of Yelmandenu.

Comment: See this post concerning the [discussion between kalla and malach](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73426/9215)

Comment: I learnt this the other day and had the same question, I hope you find an answer

Answer (score 1):

Side-note: Some scholars believe that this is the midrashic version of the apocryphal [Book of Tobit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Tobit) (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119782/20472) for more information). Personally, I am of the opinion that Chazal did not view the details of Tobit as historical<sup>1</sup>, but did see the core of the story as something that may have happened - thus writing it in the form of a midrash.

To your question. You translate "הקדוש ברוך הוא נוצר לבחוניו, כאדם הנוצר אישון עינו" as "G-d protects his chosen ones, like man protects the pupil of his eye" - I disagree with this translation. That would be correct if the word was בחיריו, but the word is בחוניו - His *tested*, as more properly translated by [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Ha%27Azinu.8.1?vhe=Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet&lang=en).

Now we can understand how this relates to the story: In the story, two people are being tested: The young man and the young woman. The young man is tested to see if he will follow Eliyahu's guidance to the letter and the young woman is tested to see if she'll continue having faith in Hashem. This is most emphasized by the moment in which she says: "The Holy One, Blessed Is He is truth and His Torah is true" - despite the fact that she can see that she's about to lose her fourth husband. Having both completed their tests, they are both rewarded: The man is rewarded by being warned by the angel that he is about to die, and so is able to tell his bride. The woman is rewarded by Hashem telling the angel to back off, and so the two are able to remain married, alive and healthy.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> As attested by the Church Father [Origen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origen) in his [Letter to Africanus](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/0414.htm):

> "Where you get your lost and won at play, and thrown out unburied on the streets, I know not, unless it is from Tobias; and Tobias (as also Judith), we ought to notice, the Jews do not use. They are not even found in the Hebrew Apocrypha, as I learned from the Jews themselves. However, since the Churches use Tobias, you must know that even in the captivity some of the captives were rich and well to do."

From here we see that the Jews at the time of Origen (the early Amoraic period, circa Rabban Gamliel III, son of Rebbi) thought Tobit could not be historically true, as how could exiled and captive Jews be rich and well to do (and I'll add, free enough to roam the Assyrian Empire as they pleased)? (and see similarly [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119482/when-were-the-books-and-the-text-of-the-torah-settled/119491#119491) Jerome's commentary on Yirmiyahu 29:22)

<sup>2</sup> A version of the midrash's story seems to have been included in the [Maaseh Buch](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Judaism/Myth-and-legend-in-the-modern-period#ref299789:%7E:text=and%20the%20Ma%CA%BFaseh%20Buch%20(1672%3B%20%E2%80%9CStory%20Book%E2%80%9D)%2C%20a%20compendium%20of%20254%20tales%20compiled%20by%20Jacob%20ben%20Abraham%20of%20Meseritz%20and%20first%20published%20at%20Basel.%20The%20latter%2C%20drawn%20mainly%20from%20the%20Talmud%2C%20was%20supplemented%20by%20later%20legends%20about%20medieval%20rabbis.) (see [here](https://archive.org/details/maasehbook0000mose/page/436/mode/2up) for an English translation).