# Why do people make Shabbos early as a zchus for a sick person?

Tags: shabbat, choleh-sick

Sometimes women will light candles and  accept the Shabbos a few minutes earlier than usual as a zchus for a sick person. How does accepting Shabbos early act as a zchus? How does it compare with davening for the choleh or saying Tehillim?

Comment: Regarding saying Tehillim, see: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64570/8775.

Answer (score 1):

The Imrei Emes is [quoted](http://www.chatzos.com/rabbinic-sources) as saying,

> By adding more kedushah of Shabbos to the home, one increases holiness
>   and purity to the family. This has the potential spiritual power to
>   counteract some of the impurities that a child may have engaged in and
>   bring him closer to purity. The more we widen the boundaries of
>   kedushah, the more narrow the territory of tumah becomes. This is the
>   power of tosefes Shabbos.

Comment: But if we are already mi'kabel Shabbos early in order to fulfill that mitzvah, does adding 10 minutes add to the mitzvah?

Comment: `The more kedusha one adds into his/her life especially on account of someone else is a great zechus` Source?